# Visual Studio 2013 regular expression To find and replace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, replace, find

In Visual Studio 2013 how can I create a regular expression to find all occurrences which are like this:

```
id="Restaurant_Viandes_Grillades" type="checkbox">
id="Another_Restaurant2" type="checkbox">
id="Another_Restaurant3" type="checkbox">
// All name Restaurants have underscore
```

...
and replace it with: `>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i have to find this :`id="([a-z_ A-Z]*)" type="checkbox">`